# jdbc nested transactions

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

What is the behaviour of nested transactions.
I am using java + jdbc ?
Eg:

```
tx1.begin
    do stuff1
    tx2.begin
        do stuff2
    tx2.commit
    do stuff1.1
tx1.rollback
```

tx2 is basically inside another function. Will the results from tx2 be persisted ?

In case behaviour is db specific, what is it in case of Sql server 2005 ?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521669/implementing-support-for-nested-transactions-using-jdbc-3-0) which is similar.